# Script to check uptime, awk its output and compare its output with gt 90 days else less then 90 days

Tags: shell

I want to develop a script which compares the uptime of a server for more than 90 days.

I have made a script already and need opinion to make it better and ask if this is going to work fine or need some corrections.

```
#!/bin/sh
output=`uptime | grep -ohe 'up .*' | sed 's/,//g' | awk '{ print $2" "$3 }'`
echo $output
if [ $output -gt "90 days"]
echo "Uptime is greater then 90 days"
else 
echo "Uptime is less then 90 days"
```

I want to run this script as a Bugfix package to check the output of Linux use servers which have uptime more than 90 days and need help in storing the output in a file in /tmp.

Comment: `-gt` can only be used with integers. You could give it "90", but not "90 days", as the word *days* isn't numeric in nature. And always, *always* quote your expansions. [`echo "$output"`, not `echo $output`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo); and [`[ "$output" -gt 90 ]`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.24foo_.3D_.22bar.22_.5D).

Comment: Affirmative, thanks  a lot Charles!!

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to use grep, sed and awk. Here is one for Linux using only awk, reading uptime info from `/proc/uptime`. `man proc`:

```
/proc/uptime
       This  file  contains  two  numbers:  the uptime of the system (seconds), 
       and the amount of time spent in idle process (seconds).
```

Let's see:

```
$ uptime
 14:36:40 up 21 days, 20:04, 12 users,  load average: 0.78, 0.85, 0.88
$ cat /proc/uptime
1886682.73 1652242.10
```

An awk script:

```
$ awk '{
    if($1>90*24*3600)
        print "Uptime is greater than 90 days"
    else 
        print "Uptime is less than or equal to 90 days"
}' /proc/uptime
```

Output for my system:

```
Uptime is less than or equal to 90 days
```